# ¿Como hacer para que cuando pase el cursor sobre una imagen encima de la imagen de una descripcion y al quitar el cursor de la imagen se quite?

Tags: imagen, class, animación, texto

Lo he intentado con css pero no encuentro como
probe con
pero el texto aparece sin que mueva encima de la imagen el cursor del mouse y no se quita me pueden ayudar?

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="I1.png" />
  <div class="texto-encima">La pre-primaria es el momento en que los pequeños inician su aventura educativa, y en Liceo Compu-Market los hacemos pasar los mejores momentos de su inicioo en la niñez.</div>
  <div class="centrado">La pre-primaria es el momento en que los pequeños inician su aventura educativa, y en Liceo Compu-Market los hacemos pasar los mejores momentos de su inicioo en la niñez.</div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Eso que describes se le conoce como Tooltip y no se hace con CSS,  es un atributo de los elementos HTML pero no recuerdo su nombre.

Answer (score 1):

espero que te sirva de ayuda mi ejemplo:

Lo que podrías realizar alternamente es lo siguiente:

```css
.contenedor {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621419079793-73020baef9eb?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=592&q=80');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;

  overflow: hidden;
}

.contenedor-texto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.contenedor:hover .contenedor-texto {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="contenedor-texto">
    <p>Texto a mostrar...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes ejecutar el código si deseas probarlo.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.texto-encima  {
  display: none;
}

.contenedor {
  position: relative;
}

.contenedor:hover .texto-encima {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #cacaca;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <img width="100%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb" />
  <div class="texto-encima">La pre-primaria es el momento en que los pequeños inician su aventura educativa, y en Liceo Compu-Market los hacemos pasar los mejores momentos de su inicioo en la niñez.</div>
  <div class="centrado">La pre-primaria es el momento en que los pequeños inician su aventura educativa, y en Liceo Compu-Market los hacemos pasar los mejores momentos de su inicioo en la niñez.</div>
</div>
```